# Relationship between Sonarqube & SonarScanner

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm in process of setup [Sonar](https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/) for my Android-Kotlin gradle based project. There I setup local system that run **./gradlew Sonarqube** and generate report.

I come across another tool sonar-runner which need to generate report. I checked sonarqube downloaded folder & that already has some sonar-scanner file & generating report without explicit setup. So do we really need sonar-scanner explicitly ?

What I understood is [SonarScanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+Source+Code) is the scanner that work for scanning & help sonarqube to generate report.

Please make me correct

Answer (score 4):

**sonar-scanner** (formerly **sonar-runner**) is useful when you don't have a build automation tool like gradle, maven, ant or jenkins.

If you build with **gradle**, then you only need the **org.sonarqube** plugin.

Here is the documentation **[Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner for Gradle](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle)**

Comment: In my case I have gradle based android project that uses Kotlin for development. I have setup Sonarqube and it's analysing & generating report well. So I guess explicit SonarScanner plugin not needed.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge sonarscanner is present inside Sonarqube and it's scans each and every code and creates a report and send it to the Sonarqube for analysis the code please correct me if I am wrong